# Codeigniter force_download() No output

Tags: codeigniter

Fast to explain, but I can't get it to work:

In this simple code, the function force_download simply doesn't make any output.

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$data = file_get_contents("upload/".$filename);
 $name = $no_file;
force_download($name, $data);
```

Here I just get a white screen, but the file content is show (well you know, the strange codified content :) I think it is simple enough, I just want the file downloaded with no other effect, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed $name is a valid string? You can also try setting the mime type argument force_download($name, $data, true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is you should do..

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$path = file_get_contents(base_url()."yourpath/".$filename); // get file name
$name = "test.pdf"; // new name for your file
force_download($name, $path); // start download`
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
Make sure you have a file extension on the filename you supply for the first argument to `force_download()`.

CodeIgniter uses this to set the MIME type, and it doesn't seem to work without.

**ERROR: Name or Service not known.**

Step1: Opening /etc/resolv.conf (my file was empty)

Step2: Add

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

options rotate
options timeout:3
```

This may help.

Comment: i was tried but eror
Message: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Comment: DNS is broke. Can you ping `data.mysite.com` from a shell on the machine (assuming you have one)?

Try replacing `data.mysite.com` with a fixed IP address for now.

Comment: i have write manually like 
base_url()."upload/thumb/004080_foto.jpg
but not work